# How many $s,t,u$ satisfy: $s +2t+3u +\ldots = n$?

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, diophantine-equations

> Given $n\in \mathbb{N}^+$, what is the possible number of combinations
>   $s,t,u,\ldots\in\mathbb{N}$, such that: $$s +2t+3u +\ldots = n\quad?$$
>   Additionally, is there an efficient way to find these combinations
>   other than an elimination process?

This problem comes from the formula for series reversion, and gives the number of terms in each inverse coefficient.

Comment: Do you assume that $0\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: @ajotatxe - $n>0$.

Comment: Are $s,t,u,\cdots \ge 1$?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay - I meant to say, that no, $s,t,u,$ can be zero as well.

Comment: Oh, ok, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  number of solutions of the equation equals the coefficient of $z^n$ in the expression 
$$
\frac{1}{(1-z)(1-z^2)(1-z^3)\ldots }=\sum_{n}p(n)z^n,
$$
where $p(n)$  is the [Euler partition function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html), so that the number of combinations is $p(n)$.

(Christoph): There is a bijection between the partition function and the desired function, since from a partition $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_k=n$ you set $s$ to the number of $1$s appearing, $t$ to the number of $2$s appearing, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure that helps :/

Comment: See my editing..

Comment: this is incorrect. Note that I'm not looking for $s+t+u+\ldots =n$, but rather $s+2t+3u+\ldots =n$

Comment: No, that is the same if we collect equal terms

Comment: how so? mind adding some detail?

Comment: @Leox The $s,t,u,\dots$ don't need to be pairwise distinct, so the bijection you have in mind is not a bijection, I think.

Comment: No, that is easy standart partition combinatorial problem and I have wrote  how to solve  it

Comment: @Leox, Numerically, it looks like you right, but it's not clear to me why. Also, it's not clear how one would go about finding the options.

Comment: Oh I was looking at it in the wrong way. From a partition $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k=n$ you would set $s$ the number of $1$s appearing, $t$ the number of $2$s appearing, etc. This is a bijection indeed.

Comment: @Christoph - well done. That completes the answer.